# Setting camera permissions on Android using Detox

Tags: android, react-native, e2e-testing, detox

**Description**

I'm testing a screen with access to the camera to get a photo. But I can't deal with the permissions dialog in tests on Android.

I run the tests with `await device.launchApp({ permissions: { camera: 'YES' }});`. This setting worked for iOS. How can I accept all permissions for Android? Or how can I handle the permissions dialog on Android?

**To Reproduce**

init.js settings

```
await device.launchApp({
  permissions: { photos: 'YES', camera: 'YES' },
});
```

emulator settings

```
{
  "configurations": {
    "android.emu.debug": {
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Nexus_S_API_27"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Environment**

- Detox: 16.2.1
- React Native: 0.60.4
- Node: 12.16.1
- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Device: emulator Nexus S API 27

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue on Detox 17.2.0, React Native 0.61, API 27 for my Android emulator. It works perfectly on iOS but on Android, whatever I set `NO` or `YES` on permissions, they are always enabled.

If I change theses permissions on the app before launching `detox test`, all permissions are enabled again.

My tests looks like the following:

```
describe('Permissions', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative()
  })

  it('displays no warning when camera and microphone access are authorized', async () => {
    await device.launchApp({ newInstance: true, permissions: { camera: 'YES', microphone: 'YES' } })
    ...
  })

  it('displays a warning message + button to app settings when camera access is denied', async () => {
    await device.launchApp({ newInstance: true, permissions: { camera: 'NO', microphone: 'YES' } })
    ...
  })
})
```

Detox can not handle this for the moment I guess if you check this issue https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2184